# Remote debugging using gdbserver

Tags: cross-compilation

I am troubling for 2 days with gdbserver running on my target. Would appreciate if anyone can point to the right direction.

Here is the scenario:

- I have a Targethost that runs GNU/Linux x86_64 with gdbserver but with no g++/gcc compiler
- I have a Localhost that runs Windows 10 and Visual Studio with gdb
- I have ssh access between Target and Localhost

Questions:

a) On Targethost when I run command "gdbserver localhost:port file.cpp", it gives "Exec format error". But when I run "gdbserver localhost:port file.so", then it start listening. Does gdpserver always require a binary/executable file?

b) I want to write a Linux supported ".so" binary; is pursuing with Visual Studio cross compilation to a Linux Host (that has no g++/gcc compiler installed) a right approch? Or is it better to get a VM with Linux with gcc/g++ installed a better one?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Regards,
Anmol

Comment: Use `eclipse` or `QtCreator` on your MS Windows machine. You can easily set them up for cross compilation and remote debugging. Only use a VM if you need to keep your build environment for future reference.

Comment: @Philippos I would like to keep my build for future reference.. Is there no way to use gdbserver together with Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio, wrong place. (-; If you want to keep your build environment, you should build inside a VM anyhow and you can as well use a linux one.

Comment: ok.. Thanks for the reply :).. I used Eclipse to cross compile and with ssh access and it worked.. In future I will give VM also a try.